# Spring Websocket with fallback over load balancer

Tags: java, spring, websocket, sockjs

We are trying to use spring-websocket with STOMP using SockJS as a fallback option. We have based our solution on this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/.

The environment is running multiple tomcats without sticky session.

The problem we have run into is that it is not possible to use the fallback from websocket 
due to the xhr requests ending up on separate tomcats where the original session does not exist, causing 
it to retry with a websocket connection and it will continue in this loop.

Is there a preferred way of solving this issue?

We were hoping that spring-session would be an answer but it does not seem to help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is one of:
1) REST services
2) sticky sessions
3) session replication

Comment: We tried third option with Spring-Session, but that failed.

Comment: @cewan, a complete different solutio, but take a look at Atmosphere, which solves this issue https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere . You just need to select the proper cloud extensions to make it work https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-extensions/.

Comment: Seems we have to use sticky sessions, since Spring Session does not yet support SockJS fallback:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12936

Comment: We are the other 5%. A lot of pushes etc

Comment: You can secure REST services too